# Best practices for unit testing in IPhone

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run and debug unit tests for an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989668/how-to-run-and-debug-unit-tests-for-an-iphone-application)

I want to unit test my IPhone application.
What tips and practices  should be followed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is my favourite one

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-quick-start-guide

[What is the best way to unit test Objective-C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207/what-is-the-best-way-to-unit-test-objective-c-code)

http://paulsolt.com/2010/11/iphone-unit-testing-explained-part-1/

http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/02/23/tdd-best-practices-testing-in-ios4-with-ghunit-part-1/

http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/02/23/tdd-best-practices-testing-in-ios4-with-ghunit-part-1/

Comment: raywenderlich and longweekendmobile tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You might want to checkout Gorilla Logic’s FoneMonkey, an open source record / playback testing tool for iPhone applications: [link for gorillalogic](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4 comes with everything you need: **OCUnit** for the unit tests - and **Instrument** has Automation which you might want to have a look at for GUI testing.